# How to get debug data from client's device efficiently

Tags: java, android, debugging, logging

I am developing an non-market third party app and I want to be able to understand what is wrong on my client's device.
So how do you suggest to do that?
I was thinking to collect all stack traces and other logs and send them to email or something similar.
Is there any general popular practice to understand what is wrong on the client's device? Any advice will be highly appreciated as I don't want to use some custom, unreliable practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to collect informations in case of a crash of your application, you could use the [**ACRA - Application Crash Report for Android**](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) library.

In case of a crash of your application, it will almost-automatically post informations *(stacktrace, device informations, ...)* to a google-document ; which is pretty helpful to analyze the cause of that crash.

You can suggest the user to write some additional information that might help you find out the cause of that crash.

Answer (score 0):

I am using BugSense it is really good and very easy to use.

http://www.bugsense.com/

Just adding 1 line to your application and it is good to go.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);          

    BugSenseHandler.setup(this, "YOUR_API_KEY");            

    // The rest of your code goes here
}
```